# UPD Multicast (Class D) = How can this be routed over the internet?

Tags: multicast

is there a simple way (without setting up a local network via VPN) to route UPD Multicast Packets (224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255) from one server to another server (both residing in completely different networks as they are hosted with different companies...)?

Thanks 
Jens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer : no. Not over the public Internet.

One way to do this is to set up a MPLS link between these two networks or a VPN.

Comment: A VPN would be the less painful option in my experience, YMMV.

Comment: I agree MPLS is more complicated then a VPN, but much more robust. MPLS is a technology that allows you to interconnect two private sites as if they were linked by a single router although they are in two different places.

Comment: Since the two sites are connected to different providers (that may not even peer with each other), MPLS would have to be tunneled over IP using GRE. Since you need GRE for MPLS and you can route multicast over GRE without MPLS, MPLS doesn't add anything but complexity in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this, you can set up two UDP multicast repeaters (one on each LAN), linked by a TCP connection (or UDP unicast).